# Zonal sum gives incorrect results

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, zonal-statistics

I have two raster files:

Raster 1 has 7974 grids (coarser resolution) with `Rowid`, `Value` and `Count`.

Raster 2 is finer resolution and each grid has values either 1 or 0.

What I want to do is to find the number of 1s in each coarser grid (Raster 1). I assumed I could do this using zonal statistics (zonal sum). I used the following settings:

Input raster or feature zone data:
`Raster 1`

Zone field:
`Value`

Input value raster:
`Raster 2`

Statistics type:
`Sum`

This should just sum up all the 1s falling under the coarser resolution and give me what I need. However, when I run it, it returns me a raster file with only two values: 1 and 0 for each of my coarser grid. What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The data is being resampled to a common resolution. Depending on you environmental settings, it could go either way but this is likely the cause of your discrepancy. In raster analysis the grids have to share the same cell resolution. ArcGIS does many things like this in the background.

Comment: Thanks. I figured this out. Going to environment settings and changing the output raster size works.