# Zonal sum not working?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, zonal-statistics

I have a raster file for India which is a cropland map with following information:

```
Columns and rows: 7015, 6582
Cell size: 0.0041666667, 0.0041666667
```

Each grid of this cropland has a value of either 1 (cropland, green) or 0 (no cropland, brown)
[image]

I have another raster file of India at a coarser resolution.

```
Columns and rows: 167, 160
Cell size: 0.16666668, 0.16666668
```

[image]

I want to calculate for each of the coarser grid, how many cropland grids are present. Presumably I could do this using `zonal sum` by setting coarse map to `input raster`and cropland map as the `input value raster`. But this is not working and it gives me a map at coarser resolution but the values are just 1 and 2. I was wondering what issue is there. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly to do with the differing resolutions (note the comments in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181649/zonal-sum-gives-incorrect-results)).  You have two options:

1. Resample your zone raster to match your values raster resolution.
2. Edit your environment settings for the calculation.

Note: J.Kelly's answer will also give you what you require but you may want to use the zones raster as a mask to the operation to account for the no data areas I see in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Spatial Analyst > Generalization > Aggregate with the SUM option and a cell factor of 40.  If you set the extent in Environments to match your coarse layer, you should get something pretty close.

It will add the values of all the smaller pixels (1+1+1+0+0+0 etc.) and write the sum, i.e, count, into larger ones.